# glob patterns difference between {} and +()

Tags: glob

I referenced https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/ and it says that

> +(pattern_list) : The pattern matches if one or more occurrences of any of the patterns in the pattern_list match the input string.
> Requires the EXTGLOB flag.
>
> {} : Bash style brace expansions. This is applied to patterns before
> anything else. Requires the BRACE flag.

I can see that the description is different for each of them, but hard to understand with the actual example.

For example, what is the difference between those two below?

```
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "eslint --fix src/",
        "tslint --fix --project .",
        "git add"
    ]
},

"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)": [
        "prettier --write",
        "eslint --fix src/",
        "tslint --fix --project .",
        "git add"
    ]
},
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` implements something similar to Bash's brace expansion. Essentially `src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}` will become:

```
[
    'src/**/*.js',
    'src/**/*.jsx',
    'src/**/*.ts',
    'src/**/*.tsx',
    'src/**/*.json',
    'src/**/*.css'
]
```

There is a time and place for this, but you can see this might be less efficient as now you are processing multiple patterns.

You can think of `+()` more like in regular expression where `+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)` would be more equivalent to `(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)+`.
So it would match things like `js` or `jsjsxtxjson` Which is not really equivalent to `{}`.

What you are probably interested in, if looking for a more efficient comparison to `{}`, is probably `@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)` which is equivalent to regular expression patterns like this `(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)` which would match just one occurrence and would match `js` but not `jsjsxtxjson`. The reason why this may be more efficient is simply that you get a single pattern as opposed to multiple patterns.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you.